# How can I make (the most) basic .htaccess file to password protect a website

Tags: html, .htaccess

What I've done to protect my website is create this `.htaccess` file in the `/var/www/html/` directory

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "One does not simply"
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

and I created an .htpasswd in my home directory by running the command `htpasswd -c /home/blah/.htpasswd alex`

but this is not working.  In fact when I visit the website I don't get any authentication pop-up or anything.

I'm doing this on a *totally clean* VPS using a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and having only installed `apache2`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make it simple:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My page is password protected!"
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

create a **.htpasswd** file add the following for username & password:

karrot:mypassword

make sure to add the .htpasswd inside the right folder.

hope this helps.

Comment: this still isn't working for me.  I've got a fresh install of apache2 on a digital ocean droplet, and I'm wondering if maybe not adding `AllowOverride AuthConfig` in some config file might be what's messing it up as it's a prerequisite according to the apache documentation.  I tried putting it in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.con` but that just broke the server